# CMS content editor radio button field

Tags: content-editor, fieldtype

Is there any way we can use Radio button in CMS content editor.

Requirement is to use Radio button in sitecore CMS content editor and based on that show hide some sections of an template?

Comment: The requirement seems unclear on why you would use a radio button to toggle the visibility of sections. You can use security to hide them, or collapse them by default, or even change the sort order. Perhaps you can provide more details, including screenshots.

Comment: Based on users/roles configuration, you can set the security on the template level including fields and sections, and i believe that should be the correct way to do it, but , yes, having more details about your requirements helps in providing the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

I understood you're trying to show/hide a set of fields depending on the selected value of radio button (in content editor).

Out of the box you can't do this.

First of all there is no Radio button in Sitecore, you may be able to do the same behaviour using a DropList or a DropLink field.

Then you're going to have to do some customization to achieve what you need. I think [this article](https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2014/04/24/hiding-content-editor-fields-depending-on-selected-values/) is what you're looking for.